# returning const char* to char* and then changing the data

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring

I am confused about the following code:

```
string _str = "SDFDFSD";
char* pStr = (char*)_str.data();
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    pStr[i] = ::tolower(pStr[i]);
```

here `_str.data()` returns `const char*`. But we are assigning it to a `char*`. My questions is,

`_str.data()`is returning pointer to a constant data. How is it possible to store it in a pointer to data? The data was constant right? If we assign it to char pointer than we can change it like we are doing inside the for statement which should not be possible for a constant data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not valid at the standard library level (you're violating `std::string contract`) but valid at the C++ core language level.

The `char *` returned from `data` should not be written to because for example it could be in theory(*) shared between different strings with the same value.

If you want to modify a string just use `std::string::operator[]` that will inform the object of the intention and will take care of creating a private buffer for the specific instance in case the string was originally shared instead.

Technically you are allowed to cast-away const-ness from a pointer or a reference, but if it's a valid operation or not depends on the semantic of the specific case. The reason for which the operation is allowed is that the main philosophy of C++ is that programmers make no mistakes and know what they are doing. For example is technically legal from a C++ language point of view to do `memcpy(&x, "hello", 5)` where `x` is a class instance, but the results are most probably "undefined behavior".

If you think that your code "works" it's because you've the wrong understanding of what "works" really should mean (hint: "works" doesn't mean that someone once observed the code doing what seemed reasonable, but that will work in all cases). A valid C++ implementation is free to do anything it wants if you run that program: that you observed something you think is fine doesn't really mean anything, may be you didn't look close enough, or may be you were just lucky (unfortunate, actually) that no crash happened right away.

(*) In modern times the COW (copy-on-write) implementations of std::string are low in popularity because they pose a lot of problems (e.g. with multithreading) and memory is a lot cheaper now. Still `std::string` contract says you're not allowed to change the memory pointed by the return value of `data()`; if you do anything may happen.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph alone. I will add that to my repertoire.

Comment: +1 nice answer. It should be noted that the briefly mentioned const-casting in C++ is only viable if the *original object* being referenced or pointed to is *itself* non-const. I.e. declare a `Object s`, pass it to a function taking `const Object&`, the function, knowing the original object was non-const, can const-cast the reference and go nuts. Were it declared `const Object s;` its becomes UB to const-cast the reference in the function. There is no guarantee the result of `std::string::data()` and/or `std::string::c_str()` were originally pointers of the non-const-ilk. Thus, *bad idea*.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. It may be fine in this case, but as the documentation for `data()` says:

> The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other
>   member functions that modify the object.
>
> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.

So you could very accidentally write to invalid memory if you keep that pointer around. Or, in fact, ruin the implementation of std::string. I would almost go as far as to say that this function shouldn't be exposed.

std::string offers a non-const `operator[]` for that purpose.

```
string _str = "SDFDFSD";
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    _str[i] = ::tolower(_str[i]);
```

Comment: what I am doing is valid. but I wanted to know why it is valid? To me it seems wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Tahlil: What you do is not valid. In C++, successful compilation does not guarantee validness; the standard is full of undefined behaviours.

Comment: It's not valid; it's Undefined Behavior and it can stop working at any time (including simply and silently discarding your changes to the string, setting your house on fire, etc.)

Comment: Thanks both of you. That's exactly the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You never must change the data returned from `std::string::data()` or `std::string::c_str()` directly.

To create a copy of a `std::string`:

```
std::string str1 = "test";
std::string str2 = str1; // copy.
```

Change characters in a string:

```
std::string str1 = "test"
str1[0] = 'T';
```

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way would be to use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) instead:

```
std::transform(_str.begin(), _str.end(), _str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: But I want to know why it is valid to assin a `pointer to constant data` to `pointer to data`?

Comment: @Tahlil It's not. Don't do it. It will most likely lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tahlil: I've told you already minutes ago that compilation success does NOT imply validness. Why are you ignoring my advice? -- edit: I realise you are just too busy at the moment :D

Comment: Not ignoring. With all these answers and edits are being made it took me time to see yours.

Comment: @Tahlil: Yeah, too much flux at the moment, sorry for the accusition ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is that in C++ you can cast away the 'const' of a variable.

You probably shouldn't though.

[See this for const correctness in C++](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html)

Answer (score 0):

String always allocates memory on heap, so this is not actually const data, it is just marked so (in method data() signature) to prevent modification.

But nothing is impossible in C++, so with a simple cast, though unsafe, you can now treat the same memory space as modifiable.

Comment: Correction: "always" means default string here, you can always write your own allocator of course.

Comment: It is not required to allocate on the heap. It may also allocate [e.g. short] strings on the stack, or large strings on hard disks.

Comment: @phresnel it actually doesn't allocate in all situations, so there might be cases where it will crash. Although n3290 mentions in the effects section that for all these cases "points at the first element **of an allocated copy** of the array whose first element is pointed at by s"

Answer (score -2):

All constants in a C/C++ program (like `"SDFDFSD"` below)will be stored in a separate section `.rodata`. This section is mapped as read-only when the binary is loaded into memory during execution.

```
int main()
{
  char* ptr = "SDFDFSD";
  ptr[0]='x'; //segmentation fault!!
  return 0;
}
```

Hence any attempt to modify the data at that location will result in a run-time error i.e. a **segmentation fault**.

---

Coming to the above question, when creating a string and assigning a string to it, a [new copy in memory now exists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) (memory used to hold the properties of the string object `_str`). This is on the heap and NOT mapped to a read-only section. The member function `_str.data()` points to the location in memory which is mapped read/write.

> The **`const`** qualifier to the return type ensure that this function is NOT accidentally passed to string manipulation functions which expect a non-const **`char*`** pointer.

In your current iteration there was no limitation on the memory location itself that was holding the string object's data; i.e. it was mapped with both read/write permissions. Hence modifying the location using another non-const pointer worked i.e. `pStr[i]` on the left hand side of an assignment did NOT result in a run-time error as there were no inherent restrictions on the memory location itself.

Again this is **NOT** guaranteed to work and just a implementation specific behaviour that you have observed (i.e. it simply happens to work for you) and cannot always depend on this.

Comment: Then how can that code is changing the constant data by first assigning to a pointer to non constant data and then changing it? The assignment should be wrong right?

Comment: This is not true. A compiler of course is allowed to do that, but it is _not_ and _cannot be_ a requirement by the standard. Also, the constant returned by a temporary `std::string` is probably not a true constant.

Comment: "Constructs the string with the contents initialized **with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s**. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if s does not point at an array of at least Traits::length(s)+1 elements of CharT."

Comment: These are implementation specific details and may vary from implementation to implementation. Brute generaliations like "All constants in C/C++" just doesn't help. Moreover you haven't answered the OP's question

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit does not make your answer correct :(

Comment: @phresnel Made it more comprehensive now. I hope it explains why it works (and when it won't) quite well now...